# React-Redux State showing init value instead of state value

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am a little stuck with some React/Redux behavior that I am trying to understand. I have a web page with a tabbed interface. Each tabbed page contains several sub-components - for example a search field and some top-level choices, which are then used to get data from a server and display it in a table below. I am using AG-Grid as the table, and some cells contain separately rendered components, as well.

In this case, here is what is happening:

1. I load the tabbed page
2. The tabbed page is initialized with an empty redux-store variable - there is no information in the table, and nothing to display in the search field
3. The user selects an item out of the search box list
4. The redux-store state is now updated with the fetched server data based on the selected search
5. The state should persist on the page. Now, if I call a function from the table (double click function), the state shows the **initialized** value and not the current **store** value. ***HOWEVER***, if I perform *any other action* on the page before trying to run the table function, the redux-store value is recalled and the code functions as expected.

Here are some snippets, since the code is too long to reproduce here.

This is the initial tabbed page that is loaded from the main page:

```
    const BuildProjectView = (props: {inputProjectObj: any}): JSX.Element => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [selectedProject, setSelectedProject] = useState<Project>(projectEmptyObj);
    
    // fetch static data (once)
    useEffect(() => {
        //...fetch the background data required to display the page
    }, []);

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <BuildView inputProjectData={selectedProject}/>
            <BuildProjectTableView />
        </React.Fragment>  
    );
}
```

In this example, there is nothing to be rendered in `selectedProject`, I pass in the initialized state. Here is the BuildView code:

```
const BuildView:React.FC<{inputProjectData: Project}> = (props) => {

    return (
        <Row>
            <Col xl={6} lg={6}>
                <ProjectSearchForm inputProjectData={props.inputProjectData}/>
            </Col>
            <Col xl={6} lg={6}>
                <FicMaterialSearchForm />
            </Col>
        </Row>
    
    );
}
```

And now, here is is ProjectSearchForm, where the redux store gets populated for the rest of the page:

```
const ProjectSearchForm = (props: {inputProjectData: Project}): JSX.Element => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    //lots of other page state controllers here
    const projectData: Project = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.buildview.selectedProject);
    const selectedBuild: Build = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.buildview.selectedBuild);
    const [selectedProject, setSelectedProject] = useState(projectEmptyObj);
<...>

const projectChangeHandler = (event: any, value: Project | null): void => {
        if (value !== null) {
            dispatch(buildViewActions.setEditOption({editOption: false}));
            const projectId: number = value?.engagement;
            setSelectedProject(value);

            // determine project builds
            dispatch(getProjectBuildData(projectId));
        }
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Form>
                <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="projectSearchField">
                    <Form.Label column xl={1} lg={1} className="mr-1">Project:</Form.Label>
                    <Col xl={7} lg={7}>
                        <Autocomplete
                            <...Autocomplete field options here...>
                            onChange={projectChangeHandler}
                            value={selectedProject}
                        />
                    </Col>
               </Form.Group>
             </Form>
          </React.Fragment>
```

At this point, my Redux store variable, `state.buildview.selectedProject` has been updated.
Now I'm interested in `ProjectBuildTableView` that was rendered as an empty table, above. `BuildProjectTableView` contains a lot of the table functions that are tracked by the various stores that populate the table, as well as the rendered components inside the table.

```
const ProjectBuildTableView = (): JSX.Element => {
  //here I'm bringing in the Redux store component that is updated from the other view
  const projectData: Project = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.buildview.selectedProject);
  const selectedBuild: Build = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.buildview.selectedBuild);
  const openNewTabWhenCellDbClicked = (data: BuildItem | SerialItem, type: string): void => {
             const tabRequest = {
                tabId: type,
                tabChangeTrigger: true,
                inputObj: {
                    data: data, 
                    //EMPTY projectData!!
                    projectData: projectData,
                    selectedBuild: selectedBuild,
                    from: 'build'
                }
            }
            dispatch(commonActions.updateTabOptions({tabRequest: tabRequest}));
}
```

After the page loads for the first time, and I have selected something from the search field, and verified that the data has been loaded into the store, I try double-clicking a cell in the table and `projectData` and `selectedBuild` are set to their initialized values (they are not undefined and they are not null, they have the initialized interface values from the instantiation of the store).

If I interact with *any other element* on the `ProjectSearchForm` component, the store retains its value, even if my interaction does not touch the store! I can double click or do any other navigation within the page and `projectData` maintains its state.

I'm pretty lost as to the cause of this issue, and I apologize if I have not provided enough information to determine the cause. I've set breakpoints and useEffects to track the change in projectData state within the component, and there is no indication that the value changes *until* I interact with the page for the first time after changing the store.

Thank you in advance for any insights!

Edit: I'd also like to point out that the state does not appear to change inside the store in debug mode. I'm checking on the Redux debugger in Chrome and the value is correctly stored. It is only in this local first page interaction that the store variable (from useSelector) is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out. I may (still) lack some understanding about the underlying function pointers and memory handling as state is passed around.
Essentially, what seemed to be happening was:

1. I am passing top-level functions down to lower-level components
2. The redux store value changed
3. The function at the lower-level did not update, even though the store values were tracked
4. The function was invoked from the lower level, but still contained stale state
   values

**Solution**: force the function at the lower level to re-render; re-sending the updated function pointer *after* state values have been updated (forced render via useEffect)

I hope other people will find this useful, and realize that React caches entire functions, rather than passing them by reference.